# Why node.js express sessions work correctly in Chrome but not in IE 10

Tags: node.js, session, express, csrf

I store my sessions in MongoDB, using ('connect-mongo')(express)

When I use chrome browser:
 Only one session with id and coockie info created in mongoDB.

When I user IE10:
 Seven sessions with id and coockies are created in mongoDB.

Also connect _csrf doesn't work in IE10 when using req.session._csrf.

Help please.

Comment: Weird.. can you show your code? Also, anyone know if favicon requests and such include cookies?  Could simply be middleware ordering.

Comment: @jmar777 I think that all requests use cookies. Yeah, I agree that's a bizarre issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The issue was cause of using Cloud9 online text pad to launch my node project and it uses 8080 port and a proxy. So IE 10 opens several sessions in this case. After I tried to start in on my local machine on 80 port, everything is ok.